# Add second order fit to scatter plot in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to add second order curve to scatterplot.
I've read the answers to previous similar questions and here's what I came up with:

```
x<-log2(c(100,500,1000,2000,4000))
y<-c(3.6,1.308,1.065,.960,.908)
plot(x,y,pch=1)
mod_<-lm(y~poly(x,2,raw=TRUE))
lines(x,predict(mod_),col='red',lty=2)
```

Still, I get linear segments instead of smooth curve.
What mistake am I not seeing here ? Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `predict` by passing the model only. This only results in the model being evaluated at the values you specified in your `lm` call (that is `x`).

You need to supply a new set of values at which the model will be evaluated.

For, instance, this gives you a nice smooth line:

```
x<-log2(c(100,500,1000,2000,4000))
y<-c(3.6,1.308,1.065,.960,.908)
plot(x,y,pch=1)
mod_<-lm(y~poly(x,2,raw=TRUE))
# Define the new points at which you want to evaluate your model
new.x <- seq(6, 12, 0.1)
lines(new.x, predict(mod_, newdata = list(x=new.x)),col='red',lty=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ggplot2` like this

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x, y)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x, y))+geom_point()+stat_smooth(method="lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw =TRUE))
```

[image]